# Encoding error when argument contains &

Tags: python, encoding, cherrypy

I am submitting a filename through a webform, and getting cherrypy to receive this file name and open it for processing. the issue I have here is when the file contains "**&**" I get the following error.
I have no issues when I remove the "&" from the filename

**filename:**

> invoicing - SP30075306 Heidelberg Dust & Dropper.xlsm

**Python code:**

```
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

@cherrypy.expose
def cost_breakdown(self, **mate):
    print mate['file'].encode('UTF8')
    offer_path = os.path.join('C:/Users/rihanio/Dropbox/Projects/Python_code/work/gateway/Temp_Project_Files/temp_invoicing', mate['file'].encode('UTF8'))
```

**Error printout:**

> invoicing - SP30075306 Heidelberg Dust
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   u'C:/Users/rihanio/Dropbox/Projects/Python_code/work/gateway/Temp_Project_Files/temp_invoicing\invoicing
>   - SP30075306 Heidelberg Dust '

Comment: The `&` character has special meaning as the field separator in a URL, should be encoded as `%26`

Comment: Code formatting is slightly off.

Comment: any suggestions to encode this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by encoding the filename on the webform side before sending to python.

> encodeURIComponent(file.name)

```
$.ajax({url: '/cost_breakdown?sp=&wo=&pm=' +cookie_read +'&contract=' +contract +'&file=' +encodeURIComponent(file.name),
```

Comment: Actually, you should encode all of your get params. I'd recommend you using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to encapsulate this.